# Error DelegatingPreparedStatement when use compositeWriter

Tags: spring, jdbc, spring-batch

## Composite writer

```
 <bean id="compositeItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemWriter">
            <property name="delegates">
              <list>                
                     <ref bean="writer1" />
                     <ref bean="writer2" />
                    </list>
                 </property>
           </bean>

  #Writer1
          <bean id="writer1" class="......TableWriter">
           <property name="assertUpdates" value="false" />
         <property name="itemPreparedStatementSetter">
               <!-- Our Mapper for table writer -->
                  <bean class="......WriterTableMapper" />
                 </property>
               <!-- Put in your INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE SQL here -->
               <property name="sql" value="dummy" />
                <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            </bean>
```

Dummy SQL set in the ...TableWriter class in beforeWrite method

```
@Override
public void beforeWrite(List< ? extends bo > items) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( );

    if ( "DELETE".equals( NAME ) ) {
        sb.append( " DELETE FROM table1 WHERE abc = ?" );
    } else {
        log.error( "Invalid sql [{}]", name );
    }

    setSql( sb.toString( ) );

}
```

*My Question is I have error when call

> compositeWriter

but no error when directly call

> writer1
>   *

Chunk
`<chunk reader="reader" writer="compositeWriter/writer1" commit-interval="10" />`

ERROR

```
`2016-02-26 18:08:55,606 ERROR | main | org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep        | Encountered an error executing step migrateFutureDated in job job-futuredated 
org.springframework.retry.ExhaustedRetryException: Retry exhausted after last attempt in recovery path, but exception is not skippable.; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [dummy]; nested exception is com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: [jcc][10145][10844][4.17.29] Invalid parameter 1: Parameter index is out of range. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProcessor$5.recover(FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.java:403) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.handleRetryExhausted(RetryTemplate.java:458) ~[spring-retry-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:320) ~[spring-retry-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:193) ~[spring-retry-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.BatchRetryTemplate.execute(BatchRetryTemplate.java:217) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.write(FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.java:420) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:199) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:75) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133) ~[spring-tx-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:77) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:368) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:198) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148) [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64) [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67) [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:165) [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144) [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134) [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:304) [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135) [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) [spring-core-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128) [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [dummy]; nested exception is com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: [jcc][10145][10844][4.17.29] Invalid parameter 1: Parameter index is out of range. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:94) ~[spring-jdbc-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72) ~[spring-jdbc-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80) ~[spring-jdbc-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:602) ~[spring-jdbc-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:614) ~[spring-jdbc-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter.write(JdbcBatchItemWriter.java:185) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at ......CompositeItemWriter.write(CompositeItemWriter.java:100) ~[bin/:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.writeItems(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:175) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doWrite(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:151) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProcessor$3.doWithRetry(FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.java:328) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:263) ~[spring-retry-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: [jcc][10145][10844][4.17.29] Invalid parameter 1: Parameter index is out of range. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.hd.a(hd.java:747) ~[db2jcc4-10.5.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.hd.a(hd.java:66) ~[db2jcc4-10.5.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.hd.a(hd.java:111) ~[db2jcc4-10.5.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.xo.l(xo.java:5987) ~[db2jcc4-10.5.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.xo.j(xo.java:5942) ~[db2jcc4-10.5.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.xo.a(xo.java:1606) ~[db2jcc4-10.5.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.xo.setString(xo.java:1595) ~[db2jcc4-10.5.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.setString(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:135) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.setString(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:135) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at .....WriterTableMapper.setValues(..WriterTableMapper.java:22) ~[bin/:na]
    at .....WriterTableMapper.setValues(..WriterTableMapper.java:1) ~[bin/:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcBatchItemWriter.java:189) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcBatchItemWriter.java:185) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:586) ~[spring-jdbc-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
```

Comment: You are showing not enough code. What is `NAME`? could it be something other than `"DELETE"`? The error indicates that you are preparing a query that does not contain a parameter placeholder, and then call `setString(1, ...)` on it.

Comment: NAME will be the parameter pass in from #Writer1.
<property name="NAME" value="DELETE" />
        
Actually i just want to archive I can set the dynamic SQL in beforeWrite method. Then the setSql( sb.toString( ) ); will help to set back the sql to xml.

      But I have no idea why when using compositeWriter, it throw me error.  I have to use compositeWriter as I have many writer.

Comment: If called directly from writer no problem. The problem why when call compositeWriter got error?